# Using setTimeout() for large values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an event to fire after five minutes.  I'm using the following code:

```
setTimeout(tweet(name, type), 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

It *is* firing after a while, but not nearly five minutes (Usually two minutes or so, but sometimes it's instant.).  What am I doing wrong?  (I've also tried setting the time to `300000` instead, same problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are calling `tweet` immediately and passing its return value to `setTimeout`.

You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`. You haven't included the code for `tweet`, but I'm going to assume that it doesn't `return` a function.

```
setTimeout(function () { tweet(name, type); }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Guess I need to go get more coffee.

Answer (score 2):

Quentin's solution works, but you can also use this form:

```
setTimeout(tweet(name, type), 5 * 60 * 1000);

function tweet(name, type) {
    return function(name, type) {
    };
}
```

It has some use cases when you want to keep some values in a closure.