# timedout function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the timed out function in jquery ?

```
setTimeout("searchClusterAction(action)",3000);

function searchClusterAction(action)
{
        var url = action
        $(location).attr('href',url);
}
```

on using timedout I'm getting error on line2

```
var action = "/search/perform/1584/xyz/["1","2","3","4,5,6"]/json
setTimeout('searchClusterAction('+action+')',3000);
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: As far as I know, that an extra method does not exists.

Comment: @BrianHoover http://w3fools.com

Comment: @BrianHoover, I was about to warn you about posting w3schools links. These posters usually get virtually stoned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function allows JavaScript to make a note to run the given function X milliseconds in the future.  (By the way, you should pass functions, not strings to `setTimeout()`, no matter what w3Schools says)

One caveat:  Don't call the function in the `setTimeout()` call like so:

```
setTimeout(foo(),1000);
```

as it will run `foo()` and then pass the *result* of `foo` to `setTimeout()`.  Simply:

```
setTimeout(function(){ foo(); },1000);
```

[Using setTimeout() for large values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950533/using-settimeout-for-large-values)

Comment: Better note: You shouldn't **ever** use W3Schools to learn anything.

Comment: may you tell why not pass strings?

Comment: @AnkitGautam for best practice, you should pass a function, rather than a string.

Comment: @SomeKittens i have read this sentence in answer also but am looking for a reason

Comment: From http://w3fools.com : "This is terrible advice. You never pass a string to setTimeout() unless you like using eval(). Passing a string also means, among other things, that you can't use any variables from your local scope. Also, the examples on this page use a ton of global variables. Bad."

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't have a special timeout function, the native one works perfectly and is easy to use.

```
 var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $('.example').fadeOut();
  },400);
```